# I can't visit a site with a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I made a chrome extension with a link inside, sometimes it works, but mostly it doesn't work, it says "messenger.com refused to connect", the link is correct, I made this so it would be easier for me to access messenger with just a click`<iframe width="500" height="400" src="https://www.messenger.com" frameborder="2" scrolling="no"></iframe>`

Comment: they set pretty strict content security policy headers for good reason, no one wants some dodgy extension embedding a hidden iframe on the page and pulling out the session tokens etc

Comment: Sounds like a network problem. If it were a security problem you would see more info in the message. Note that extensions can strip these security restrictions forcibly and embed any site.

Comment: what is "iframe" anyway?

Comment: I am also an edge chrome developer weeks ago